# Monte Carlo estimate of p-value for F-statistic in ANOVA based on permutation method

Tags: r, permutation, lm, anova, p-value

I am trying to do a permutation test for ANOVA on (y<sub>1</sub>,...,y<sub>N</sub>) with group identifiers `g`. I am supposed to be using (1)/(g-1) summation of (muhat<sub>j</sub> - muhat)^2 as the test statistic and muhat<sub>j</sub> is the jth group sample mean, and muhat=(1/g)summation muhat<sub>j</sub>.

```
## data
y <- c(6.59491, 6.564573, 6.696147, 6.321552, 6.588449, 6.853832, 
6.370895, 6.441823, 6.227591, 6.675492, 6.255462, 6.919716, 6.837458, 
6.41374, 6.543782, 6.562947, 6.570343, 6.993634, 6.666261, 7.082319, 
7.210933, 6.547977, 6.330553, 6.309289, 6.913492, 6.597188, 6.247285, 
6.644366, 6.534671, 6.885325, 6.577568, 6.499041, 6.827574, 6.198853, 
6.965038, 6.58837, 6.498529, 6.449476, 6.544842, 6.496817, 6.499526, 
6.709674, 6.946934, 6.23884, 6.517018, 6.206692, 6.491935, 6.039925, 
6.166948, 6.160605, 6.428338, 6.564948, 6.446658, 6.566979, 7.17546, 
6.45031, 6.612242, 6.559798, 6.568082, 6.44193, 6.295211, 6.446384, 
6.658321, 6.369639, 6.066747, 6.345537, 6.727513, 6.677873, 6.889841, 
6.724438, 6.379956, 6.380779, 6.50096, 6.676555, 6.463236, 6.239091, 
6.797642, 6.608025)

## group
g <- structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("B1", "B2", "B3"), class = "factor")
```

This is what I have right now, but it is not working when I change it to test for the sample means instead of the F statistic. I'm pretty sure that I need to change `T.obs` and `T.perm` to something similar to `by(y, g, mean)` but I think there is more that I am missing.

```
n <- length(y) #sample size n
T.obs<- anova(lm(y ~ g))$F[1]   #Observed statistic 
n.perm <- 2000   # we will do 2000 permutations
T.perm <- rep(NA, n.perm)   #A vector to save permutated statistic
for(i in 1:n.perm) {
  y.perm <- sample(y, n, replace=F)   #permute data
  T.perm[i] <- anova(lm(y.perm ~ g))$F[1]   #Permuted statistic
  }
mean(T.perm >= T.obs)   #p-value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know what you mean by "**it is not working**". As far as I can see, it works alright, except that it is slightly slow.

```
set.seed(0)
n <- length(y) #sample size n
T.obs <- anova(lm(y ~ g))$F[1]   #Observed statistic 
n.perm <- 2000   # we will do 2000 permutations
T.perm <- rep(NA, n.perm)   #A vector to save permutated statistic
for(i in 1:n.perm) {
  y.perm <- sample(y, n, replace=F)   #permute data
  T.perm[i] <- anova(lm(y.perm ~ g))$F[1]   #Permuted statistic
  }
mean(T.perm >= T.obs)
# [1] 0.4915
```

This is fairly close to the theoretical value

```
anova(lm(y ~ g))$Pr[1]
# [1] 0.4823429
```

So, yes, you are doing all correct!

---

From the first paragraph of your question it sounds like we want to compute F-statistic ourselves, so the following function does this. There is a switch `"use_lm"`. If set `TRUE`, it uses `anova(lm(y ~ g))` as what is done in your original code. **This function aims to make computation of F-statistic and p-value transparent**. Also, manual computation is 15 times faster than calling `lm` and `anova` (which is an obvious thing...).

```
fstat <- function (y, g, use_lm = FALSE) {
  if (!use_lm) {
    ## group mean (like we are fitting a linear model A: `y ~ g`)
    mu_g <- ave(y, g, FUN = mean)
    ## overall mean (like we are fitting a linear model B: `y ~ 1`)
    mu <- mean(y)
    ## RSS (residual sum of squares) for model A
    RSS_A <- drop(crossprod(y - mu_g))
    ## RSS (residual sum of squares) for model B
    RSS_B <- drop(crossprod(y - mu))
    ## increase of RSS from model A to model B
    RSS_inc <- RSS_B - RSS_A
    ## note, according to "partition of squares", we can also compute `RSS_inc` as
    ## RSS_inc <- drop(crossprod(mu_g - mu))
    ## `sigma2` (estimated residual variance) of model A
    sigma2 <- RSS_A / (length(y) - nlevels(g))
    ## F-statistic
    fstatistic <- ( RSS_inc / (nlevels(g) - 1) ) / sigma2
    ## p-value
    pval <- pf(fstatistic, nlevels(g) - 1, length(y) - nlevels(g), lower.tail = FALSE)
    ## retern
    return(c(F = fstatistic, pval = pval))
    }
  else {
    anovalm <- anova(lm(y ~ g))
    return(c(F = anovalm$F[1L], pval = anovalm$Pr[1L]))
    }
  }
```

Let's first have a check on the validity of this function:

```
F_obs <- fstat(y, g)
#        F      pval 
#0.7362340 0.4823429 

F_obs <- fstat(y, g, TRUE)
#        F      pval 
#0.7362340 0.4823429
```

Don't be surprised that it is insignificant. Your data does not really suggest significant group difference. Look at the boxplot:

```
boxplot(y ~ g)    ## or use "factor" method of `plot` function: `plot(g, y)`
```

[image]

Now we move on to the permutation. We write another function `perm` for this purpose. It is actually pretty easy, because we have a nicely defined `fstat`. All we need to do is to use `replicate` to wrap up `sample` + `fstat`.

`lm` is actually very slow:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fstat(y, g), fstat(y, g, TRUE), times = 200)

#Unit: microseconds
#              expr     min      lq      mean  median      uq      max neval cld
#       fstat(y, g)  228.44  235.32  272.1204  275.34  290.20   388.84   200  a 
# fstat(y, g, TRUE) 4090.00 4136.72 4424.0470 4181.02 4450.12 16460.72   200   b
```

so we write this function using `f(..., use_lm = FALSE)`:

```
perm <- function (y, g, n) replicate(n, fstat(sample(y), g)[[1L]])
```

Now let's run it with `n = 2000` (setting random seed for reproducibility):

```
set.seed(0)
F_perm <- perm(y, g, 2000)

## estimated p-value based on permutation
mean(F_perm > F_obs[[1L]])
# [1] 0.4915
```

Note how close it is to the theoretical p-value:

```
F_obs[[2L]]
# [1] 0.4823429
```

As you can see, the result agrees with your original code.

Comment: The original code is looking at the f statistic, and I am trying to alter it  to test for the sample means.

Comment: I really don't know, I am not 100% sure of what I'm even solving for.

Comment: I'll accept your answer, you did a really great job of breaking down and explaining everything, and I really appreciate it. It is difficult when I don't understand what I am trying to do